# Windows 7 private encrypted Documents and Settings for a certain user

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I am working on a computer at work and i would like to save some of my passwords in the browser autocomplete. Is there any way to encrypt the Documents and Settings folder for my user so that another user with administrator rights cannot login as me or read my passwords.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer encrypts your web passwords using your login password, so even if an admin changes it and logs in as you, they won’t read your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Bitlocker can encrypt anything on your computer, but only comes as part of the Windows 7 "Business" and/or "Ultimate" editions.

If you're worried about securing your passwords in web-pages, look at "[LastPass](https://lastpass.com/)".  It stores all passwords in an easy-to-use interface compatible with Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.  Additionally, without the master-password, nobody can get your passwords.  (they are never stored un-encrypted.  Not even the LastPass team can recover your passwords if you lose the master password.)  The best part is... the program is cloud-centric... one account, use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

[KeePass](http://keepass.info/) is a great tool for this purpose. However, it doesn't integrate into your browser. I've used it for years on workstations and even on Android phones. Obviously this doesn't encrypt your entire Documents and Settings folder, but it will address your desire for protected passwords.

For storage of files I'd suggest looking at [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). You can create a single-file "disk" (much like a disk image used by virtual machines) and store anything you need therein. TrueCrypt will mount it just like a normal drive on your workstation.

Both products above are open source.